# Finding Occurrences of KeyWords in List Not Working

Tags: python, python-3.x

The last issue that is facing me on this project is a function we are given to determine if a word is in another list:

```
def find_word(hash, word, g):
    Tsize = len(hash)
    max = int(Tsize/2)
    wordlen = len(word)
    try:
        g_first = g[word[0]]
    except:
        return False
    for i in range(0, max + g_first):
        h = (wordlen + i) % Tsize
        if hash[h] == word:
            return True
    return False
```

So my arguments that I pass to the function are:

```
hash = ['will', 'am', 'as', 'i', 'go', 'in', 'down', 'to', 'what', 'happy', 'today', 'greatest', 'nation', 'history', 'join', 'demonstration', 'of', 'with', 'our', 'the', 'freedom', 'you', 'for']
g = {'d': 2, 'n': 6, 'f': 14, 'm': 2, 't': 16, 'y': 15, 'o': 15, 'r': 2, 'i': 25, 'e': 1, 'g': 2, 'w': 14, 'h': 3, 'a': 13, 's': 1, 'j': 1, 'u': 1, 'l': 1}
```

and the word argument is essentially MLK's *I have a Dream Speech* converted into a list, minus the first paragraph. I bring that up because when I put in just `history` for the hash argument to check if the program works in this code:

```
counter = 0

for word in speechFileWords:
    if find_word('history', word, letters) == True:
        counter += 1

print(counter)
```

The print statement afterwards should then just print a 0, because history doesn't appear in the speech file that we were given. However, the counter returns a 14 for whatever reason, and I have no idea why it does that. Does anyone have a clue as to what is going wrong?

Comment: What is the `g` dictionary for?

Comment: How is `speechFileWords` defined? How is `letters` defined?

Comment: None of the words in `hash` are keys in `g`.

Comment: You are passing 'history' as parameter, but than it is referred to locally as 'hash'. Is this supposed to be the 'hash' with all the words you gave before?